# suspend a thread in c

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, ncurses

I'm writing a program in C where I need multithreading (pthread).
The thread is created several times, let's say 5. I use `ncurses` (kind of graphical windows in the terminal) where I have added some buttons and I want to click on the button to suspend the thread and click again to resume it.

These threads work together and they are related with another thread that blocks these threads, until a valid condition is met, and then let them continue working (I use condition variables and mutex to do that).

I'm blocked on how to be able to suspend one thread. I thought about doing a condition variable but if I do that then I need a condition variable for each thread. I found a function called `pthread_kill` but it doesn't work and stops all the program.

Many people have the same problem, is there any way to do that using signals maybe?
I don't know if the code is useful, because what I need is the idea but I'm putting it anyway.

This is the function of the thread that will be repeated 5 times

```
void* update(void* arg)
{
int statut;

threadUpdate tu;

tu = *(threadUpdate*)arg;

while(1)
{

    statut = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if(statut!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur lock mutex\n");
    }       

    scene_update2(tu.scene, tu.i);
    /*scene_update(tu.scene);*/

    *(tu.traitementTermine)=*(tu.traitementTermine)+1;

    if(*(tu.traitementTermine)==*(tu.nbObjets))
    {
        statut = pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
        if(statut!=0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Erreur cond signal\n");
        }
    }

    statut = pthread_cond_wait(&cond2,&mutex);
    if(statut!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur cond wait\n");

    }

    statut = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    if(statut!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur unlock mutex\n");
    }   
}


return NULL;}
```

The thread that will be created once just contains some mutex to control the condition variable with other threads. This is working and I have no problem with it.

Comment: Rip out everything that's not relevant to understanding that one aspect of multithreading. So, make that two (one additional) threads and remove ncurses. Then, think about how condition variables work between two threads and read some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [semaphores](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-posix-semaphores-c/). You should be able to get a system of signaling with semaphores for each of your threads and the variables they're working with.